# Comma or no comma in reaffirmation of answer? "____ it is" or "____, it is"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Would sentence 3 get a comma or not?

1. Carrie: What time do you want to get lunch?
2. Corin: How about noon?
3. Carrie: Noon, it is!  **OR**  Noon it is!

In case it's not obvious, the intention of sentence 3 is that Carrie is reaffirming Corin's answer, *not* stating, Yoda-like, that the current time is now noon.

Comment: No comma, it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would not add the comma. It's just an inversion, instead of saying "[OK then] it is noon."